# apache camel route builder not able to build dynamic route with simple language spring-boot 2.7.15 and apache- camel 3.21.0

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

This is a already working application with spring-boot 2.5.12 and apache camel 3.11.0 - now I am upgrading spring boot version to 2.7.15 and it forces me to upgrade apache camel to 3.21.0. And  while running the application the camel routes are not properly built and failing due to following exception: If anyone could help - it would really appreciable.

> org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route myRoute at: >>> DynamicTo[{{rest.endpoint.base}}/simple{${in.header.one}}/v1/simple{${in.header.two}}] <<< in route: Route(myRoute)[From[direct:myRoute... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: {{rest.endpoint.base}}/simple{${in.header.one}}/v1/simple{${in.header.two}} due to: Missing {{ from the text: http://172.143.21.21:1111/some-endpoint/simple{${in.header.one}}/v1/simple{${in.header.two}}

```
@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder {
    private static final String REST_BASE_URL = "{{rest.endpoint.base}}";
    private static final String HEADER_ONE = "${in.header.one}";
    private static final String HEADER_TWO = "${in.header.two}";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:myRoute")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods.POST)).marshal()
                .json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
                .toD(REST_BASE_URL + "/" + simple(HEADER_ONE) + "/v1/"
                        + simple(HEADER_TWO))
                .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, HashMap.class).routeId("myRoute");
    }
}
```

Comment: Found one solution -- The simple() function is not required to resolve ${in.header.one} if this expression is already with in toD() dynamic destination. If simple is used otherwise then it is resolved fine. But inside dynamic destination toD() simple function is not resolved for camel version 3.21.0 - or in other words we can say in camel 3.21.0 it is not necessary to provide expression in simple() method inside dynamic destination. the expression is resolved anyway. 

                .toD(REST_BASE_URL + "/" + HEADER_ONE + "/v1/"+ HEADER_TWO)
this above code works fine.